# Extract numeric value from element and divide it by some number

Tags: javascript, extract, numeric, divide

It's my first time posting here, so be mindful with my lack of coding skills.

So, I've been trying hard to make this code to work out and nothing worked so far. I want to extract the numeric value of an HTML and get this numeric value divided and parse the results inside a span tag.

It's important to say that I can't change this HTML easily because it's an output from a WordPress plugin.

So, this is what I've came with my javascript and HTML code:

```js
function parcelamentoFinal() {
  var precoFinal = document.getElementById("finalPrice").firstElementChild;
  var n = Number(precoFinal.replace(/[^0-9\.-]+/g, ""));

  if (isNumeric(n) == true) {
    var divide = Math.round(n / 4);
    document.getElementById("parcelamento").innerHTML = divide;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("parcelamento").innerHTML = 'Não existe valor final.';
  }
}

function isNumeric(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

```html
<h3 id="finalPrice" style=""><span>R$200</span></h3>
```

And I want to output the result in this HTML:

```
<p>ou até 4x de <span id="parcelamento"></span>, sem juros!</p>
```

Well, it's not working.

Can you guys help me out, please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `firstElementChild` is a `<span>` so may take its `textContent` ...

Answer (score 0):

Your replace method is failing because precoFinal is not evaluaed.
Use

```
var precoFinal = document.getElementById("finalPrice").firstElementChild.innerHTML;
```

Don't forget to call your method.